# How to read certain parts of a file and store it into an array in java

Tags: java

so I currently have a String array called Hotel. In this array, the elements contains names of people who are staying in a hotel. (I wrote a while loop and the user just enters a room number and a name. The room number corresponds to the array index and the name contains the element for that particular index. E.g. 3 Jim, in the array, the 4th index would be contained with the element 'Jim'. I cannot use a arraylist, only array.. part of the specificication i was handed).

This is part of the whole program. This is the method I wrote to save the array data into a file:

```
private static void savingToFile(String[] hotelRef) {
    System.out.println("Creating a text file called Hotel Data");
    File fileObject = new File("C://Hotel_Data.txt");

    if (!fileObject.exists()) {
        try {
            fileObject.createNewFile();
            System.out.println("File has been created in the C directory");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Something went wrong in the process " + e);
        }
    }

    try {
        FileWriter fs = new FileWriter(fileObject);
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(fs);

        for (int i = 0; i < hotelRef.length; i++) {
            String hoteldata = i + " " + hotelRef[i];
            writer.write(hoteldata);
            writer.newLine();
        }
        writer.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong " + e);
    }

}
```

I've runned the program and it works fine. Outputs a file in which it contains the room number and the name of the person currently occupied in that room.
Now I need to make another method in which I can load the data from the file into the array but I don't know how get the individual parts in the file. E.g. I dont know how to only get the name from the data without getting the room number..

Answer (score 1):

Just read the file and use String.split method to get the room number and name. Something like this:

```
  String[] hotelRef = new String[MAX_NO_OF_ROOMS];
  FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("Hotel_Data.txt");
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
  String hotelLine;

  while((hotelLine = br.readLine())!= null)
  {
     //split the line contents
     String hotelLineItems[] = hotelLine.split("\\s");
     Integer roomNo = Integer.valueOf(hotelLineItems[0]);
     String name = hotelLineItems[1];
     hotelRef[roomNo] = name;
  }
```

Comment: His array is not containing numbers its containing Names i dont thing that you save names as numbers you Could get an Exeption if Name arent numbers as he desribed in his Question Inside the Array are Strings and no Numbers so you cant do Integer name = Integer.valueOf(hotelLineItems[1]);

Comment: @Gorock thanks for the comment, i copy pasted the line for name wrongly. Update the code, seems OK now.

Comment: @JunedAhsan Thanks. I understand that and it works (although I had to surround it with a try/catch block). Anyways, can you tell me what the difference is between that code and this in order to read from a file:
Scanner rf = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new
 FileReader("C:\\example\\example.txt")));

Comment: @user3323950 A FileInputStream reads raw bytes from the file but Scanner parses the file as whitespace-separated tokens, and try the convert each token into the requested type when you ask for it. Choice is yours